# Scroll priority in css without jquery

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have three sticky `div`'s in my boostrap container with different heights.

Is it possible to set scroll priority for my main container?

```
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="side-l" class="col-sm-3">
          <p>Sidebar left</p>
          <p class="bottom-most">This is not that important</p>
        </div>
        <div id="main"  class="col-sm-7">
          <p>Main</p>
          <p class="bottom-most">I want to see this asap</p>
        </div>
        <div id="side-r"  class="col-sm-2">
           <p>Sidebar right</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Case now:**
When I scroll, the main container does not scroll until `side-l` reaches the bottom.

**My goal:**
When I scroll, the main container should scroll immediately when the div-height is larger than window-height.

***Note*** The heights of containers can vary based on its content. They don't have fixed heights.

If this is not possible, is there an option, where you can only scroll the hovered element?

**Js fiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/h5m7ovsb/3/

Answer (score 0):

I have added a fiddle link below. Please check if this could help you.

I have edited the below CSS code:

```
#side-l {
  height: 1800px;
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.1);
  position: relative; 
  top: 0px; 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xLmuffyx/

Comment: No, it does not help.I want to scroll main container to scroll immediately.